# element-wise merge np.array in multiple pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I got a pandas dataframe, in which there are several columns’ value are np.array， I would like to merge these np.arrays into one array elementwise based row.

e.g

```
 col1          col2        col3 
[2.1, 3]      [4, 4]      [2, 3] 
[4, 5]        [6, 7]      [9, 9] 
[7, 8]        [8, 9]      [5, 4] 
...             ...         ...
```

expected result:

```
col_f
[2.1, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3] 
[4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 9] 
[7, 8, 8, 9 5, 4]
```

........

I use kind of for loop to realize it, but just wondering if there is the more elegant way to do it.

below is my for loop cod:

```
f_vector = []
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    vector = np.hstack((df['A0_vector'][i], items_df['A1_vector'][i], items_df['A2_vector'][i], items_df['A3_vector'][i], items_df['A4_vector'][i], items_df['A5_vector'][i])) 
    f_vector.append(vector)
X = np.array(f_vector)
```

Comment: How about a `column_stack` of the individual Series (or their `.values`)?  What does `df.values` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [numpy.concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) with apply along axis=1:

```
import numpy as np
df['col_f'] = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].apply(np.concatenate, axis=1)
```

If those were lists instead of np.arrays, `+` operator would have worked:

```
df['col_f'] = df['col1'] + df['col2'] + + df['col3']
```

*Note: edited after comments thread below.*

Comment: Hi Julian, if use + operator, these arrays will plus together, I don't want them to be added, just like kind of extend. e.g the array in each column has 5 elements, once merged the 5 columns, then the total element in the new array will be 25 elements. if we use + operator, the final array will have only 5 elements only, right?

Comment: No, it's concatenating the arrays as you want, not adding the elements. It will have the 25 elements.

Comment: At least for pandas version `0.22.0`. Give it a shot and let me know if it doesn't work. I just reproduced the same example you wanted: `[2.1, 3] [4, 4]  [2, 3] ==> [2.1, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3]` with the line I posted.

Comment: No, I am using pandas 0.23, it's addition, not the way I want.

Comment: That's weird. What about `df['col_f'] = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].sum(axis=1)`?

Comment: Plus is join for lists, but addition for numpy arrays.

Comment: Nice catch, I wasn't aware of that and my code it's actually adding as @Kevin Li said in my environment too. Sorry for that. This does work with list of np.arrays: `df['col_f'] = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].apply(np.concatenate, axis=1)` (`import numpy as np` before). I'm editing my question adding all this information.

Comment: Hi Julian, df['col_f'] = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].apply(np.concatenate, axis=1) is working as what I want. thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear :)